# Does Google reCaptcha enough for preventing from brute force attacks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, recaptcha, brute-force

In my Java application (with Spring Boot) I implemented **Google reCaptcha v3** and now I am trying to implement such a mechanism in order to prevent from brute force attacks on Login form. I want to make an implementation as mentioned on [Spring Security Brute Force Protection](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/spring-security-brute-force-protection/) by checking the invalid login attempts and then disable account for a period of time after 3 failed login attempts.

However, while searching other possible scenarios or mechanisms, I have seen that Google reCaptcha may also be useful for this aim. But I am not sure if an extra implementation (besides Google reCaptcha) is useful for preventing from brute force attacks.

So, is Google reCaptcha enough or should I need an extra implementation as mentioned on [Spring Security Brute Force Protection](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/spring-security-brute-force-protection/). Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

All that a CAPTCHA does is attempt to prove that your user is a human. Google's reCaptcha is a good start for client-side security but really you want to layer multiple forms of protection.

This might include disabling the account as you describe, throttling the number of login requests for a given period & IP, or requiring that an email is sent to authorise an unrecognised login. This is largely a design decision on your part.

Baeldung has a [good article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts) on preventing brute force attacks using Spring Security that provides a workable example of IP blocking based on number of attempts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good explanations, voted up. I will definitely follow one of the suitable article on Baeldung. But I am wondering if the article you mentioned also give me a chance to clock user by username instead of ip? Because, blocking ip may not be good idea if there are several users from the same company as they also have the same ip addresses. Am I right?

Comment: @Rosa you could just change the method `loadUserByUsername` to do what you require. You are right in that IPs can be shared. This is particularly true of mobile networks, too.

Comment: I wtarted to implement your suggested page and I was exactly at that point and just added the `if (loginAttemptService.isBlocked(ip)) {}` block and `getClientIP` method. However, I am not sure how to add `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` to my maven, because there is not a library of it in Maven Repo. Any idea?

Comment: @see with importing the "spring-context" package with maven (normally it is included with spring boot, but not all the time, it depends how you have made your bundle).